# How do I prove that this sum will diverge by direct comparison test

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

I'm currently trying to solve:

> Prove this series diverges by direct comparison $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n^7-65}}{\sqrt{n^9+3n-1}}
> $$

**My attempts**

I currently do not know how to prove to fully prove that this summation diverges. Currently, I have managed to obtain a larger expression on the right hand side.

$$ \frac{\sqrt{n^7-65}}{\sqrt{n^9+3n-1}} \geqslant \frac{\sqrt{n^7-65}}{\sqrt{4n^9}}
$$

After this I'm not really sure what to do after.

Comment: Can you prove something like $n^7-65 > \frac13n^7$ for $n\ge2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n>3$ we have

$$n^7 > 130$$

and

$$n^9 > 3n-1$$

therefore we have directly that

$$\frac{\sqrt{n^7-65}}{\sqrt{n^9+3n-1}} > \frac{\sqrt{n^7-\frac{n^7}{2}}}{\sqrt{n^9+n^9}} = \frac{1}{2n}$$

and the series diverges by direct comparison test.